# Check Google Cloud Storage URI (gs://) contains a file from C#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform

I have an API endpoint that creates files in Google Cloud Storage, and in the end it returns the URI in the `gs://bucket_name/file_name` format.

How can I write tests in C# to check if the file is indeed created in the cloud? I can download the file with gcutil, but I have not found any library in C# that can handle the `gs://` URI to check/download the file.

Answer (score 2):

The [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-csharp) shows how to download objects from buckets

```
using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class DownloadFileSample
{
    public void DownloadFile(
        string bucketName = "your-unique-bucket-name",
        string objectName = "my-file-name",
        string localPath = "my-local-path/my-file-name")
    {
        var storage = StorageClient.Create();
        using var outputFile = File.OpenWrite(localPath);
        storage.DownloadObject(bucketName, objectName, outputFile);
        Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded {objectName} to {localPath}.");
    }
}
```

Also you can

```
string fileDownloadPath = @"C:\pathwereyouwanttosavefile\file_Out.pdf";
string objectBlobName = "fileName.pdf";
var gcsStorage = StorageClient.Create();
using var outputFile = File.OpenWrite(fileDownloadPath);
gcsStorage.DownloadObject(bucketName, objectBlobName, outputFile);
 
Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded {objectBlobName} to {fileDownloadPath}.");
```

[Here](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/upload-and-download-files-using-c-google-cloud-storage/) you can find more about this implementation

Finally also in the [Official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#cli-download-object) shows how to do it with gsutil

```
gsutil cp gs://BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME SAVE_TO_LOCATION
```

You can try to download the object and check for a successful response in order to see if object was created