# How to access GSUTIL though C# process class?

Tags: c#, cmd, process, gcloud, gsutil

I have gCloud configured on my laptop. With Powershell `gsutil ls` is listing the name of bucket.

But with the following C# code I am not getting any output!

```
Process process = new Process();
// Configure the process using the StartInfo properties.
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/k gsutil ls > C:\Users\gaurav.sharma\Desktop\Output.txt";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

I should ideally get same response in Output.txt. But my execution is stuck and there is no output at all.
What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71442562/18265570)?

Comment: Your code does not check for errors. On Windows, `gsutil` is a batch file. That means you must start an interpreter to run the batch file.  Use `cmd.exe /c gsutil.cmd`. Review this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5519517/8016720) for better ways to run programs from c#.

Comment: Also the option `/k` is for running built-in commands. `gsutil` is definitely not a built-in command.